# Assigning command output into a variable

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using AHK. I wanted to put output into a variable. Is anyone here know how to put the output of this command into a variable? Thanks in advance!

```
C:\Users\malik>net start | find /c /i "automate"
2

C:\Users\malik>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [AHK documentation on Run](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm). The second example provides a way to do this:

```autohotkey
; The following can be used to run a command and retrieve its output:
MsgBox % RunWaitOne("dir " A_ScriptDir)

; ...or run multiple commands in one go and retrieve their output:
MsgBox % RunWaitMany("
(
echo Put your commands here,
echo each one will be run,
echo and you'll get the output.
)")

RunWaitOne(command) {
    ; WshShell object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99
    shell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
    ; Execute a single command via cmd.exe
    exec := shell.Exec(ComSpec " /C " command)
    ; Read and return the command's output
    return exec.StdOut.ReadAll()
}

RunWaitMany(commands) {
    shell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
    ; Open cmd.exe with echoing of commands disabled
    exec := shell.Exec(ComSpec " /Q /K echo off")
    ; Send the commands to execute, separated by newline
    exec.StdIn.WriteLine(commands "`nexit")  ; Always exit at the end!
    ; Read and return the output of all commands
    return exec.StdOut.ReadAll()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/maz-1/768bf7938e533907d54bff276db80904

A library for capturing command line output without cmd window

```
StdOutStream( sCmd, Callback = "", WorkingDir=0) { ; Modified  :  maz-1
  Static StrGet := "StrGet"           ; Modified  :  SKAN 31-Aug-2013 
                                      ; Thanks to :  HotKeyIt         
                                      ; Original  :  Sean 20-Feb-2007 
  tcWrk := WorkingDir=0 ? "Int" : "Str"
  DllCall( "CreatePipe", UIntP,hPipeRead, UIntP,hPipeWrite, UInt,0, UInt,0 )
  DllCall( "SetHandleInformation", UInt,hPipeWrite, UInt,1, UInt,1 )
  If A_PtrSize = 8
  {
    VarSetCapacity( STARTUPINFO, 104, 0  )      ; STARTUPINFO          ;  
    NumPut( 68,         STARTUPINFO,  0 )      ; cbSize
    NumPut( 0x100,      STARTUPINFO, 60 )      ; dwFlags    =>  STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x100
    NumPut( hPipeWrite, STARTUPINFO, 88 )      ; hStdOutput
    NumPut( hPipeWrite, STARTUPINFO, 96 )      ; hStdError
    VarSetCapacity( PROCESS_INFORMATION, 24 )  ; PROCESS_INFORMATION  ;  
  }
  Else
  {
    VarSetCapacity( STARTUPINFO, 68, 0  )
    NumPut( 68,         STARTUPINFO,  0 )
    NumPut( 0x100,      STARTUPINFO, 44 )
    NumPut( hPipeWrite, STARTUPINFO, 60 )
    NumPut( hPipeWrite, STARTUPINFO, 64 )
    VarSetCapacity( PROCESS_INFORMATION, 16 )
  }

  If ! DllCall( "CreateProcess", UInt,0, UInt,&sCmd, UInt,0, UInt,0 ;  
              , UInt,1, UInt,0x08000000, UInt,0, tcWrk, WorkingDir
              , UInt,&STARTUPINFO, UInt,&PROCESS_INFORMATION ) 
   Return "" 
   , DllCall( "CloseHandle", UInt,hPipeWrite ) 
   , DllCall( "CloseHandle", UInt,hPipeRead )
   , DllCall( "SetLastError", Int,-1 )     

  hProcess := NumGet( PROCESS_INFORMATION, 0 )                 
  hThread  := NumGet( PROCESS_INFORMATION, A_PtrSize )  

  DllCall( "CloseHandle", UInt,hPipeWrite )

  AIC := ( SubStr( A_AhkVersion, 1, 3 ) = "1.0" ) ;  A_IsClassic 
  VarSetCapacity( Buffer, 4096, 0 ), nSz := 0 

  While DllCall( "ReadFile", UInt,hPipeRead, UInt,&Buffer, UInt,4094, UIntP,nSz, Int,0 ) {

   tOutput := ( AIC && NumPut( 0, Buffer, nSz, "Char" ) && VarSetCapacity( Buffer,-1 ) ) 
              ? Buffer : %StrGet%( &Buffer, nSz, "CP0" ) ; formerly CP850, but I guess CP0 is suitable for different locales

   Isfunc( Callback ) ? %Callback%( tOutput, A_Index ) : sOutput .= tOutput

  }                   

  DllCall( "GetExitCodeProcess", UInt,hProcess, UIntP,ExitCode )
  DllCall( "CloseHandle",  UInt,hProcess  )
  DllCall( "CloseHandle",  UInt,hThread   )
  DllCall( "CloseHandle",  UInt,hPipeRead )
  DllCall( "SetLastError", UInt,ExitCode  )
  VarSetCapacity(STARTUPINFO, 0)
  VarSetCapacity(PROCESS_INFORMATION, 0)

Return Isfunc( Callback ) ? %Callback%( "", 0 ) : sOutput      
}
```